# installation failed!! says hdd is read only?

Tags: read-only

I had an old laptop and wanted to install ubuntu onto it, used my other pc running ubuntu to create a startup usb, booted from usb, chose install to hdd, chose erase erase disk and install ubuntu (used to have windows vista) it started installation, got all the way to copying files and then crashed! Said couldn't install because the hdd is read only! So I went into disk utility and formatted the disk and tried again, same thing happened, how do I change the read/write permissions!?!?!?

Comment: Is your Vista hibernated?

Comment: Hmmm, in not sure, I haven't used that laptop since I got my new one, just plugged in my pendrive and never thought twice about it! But, I reformatted it, so shouldn't that have removed vista anyway?

Comment: I think, the BIOS sets `RO` if the OS was hibernated.